# regex get number betwen quotes

Tags: php, json, string, find

i have difrent string json type egz formats in line

```
{"env":"stato","usc":"00000000","isc":"000100","sn":"0120xxxxmacxxx"}
{{"cmd":"stat"},{"usc":"00000000",{"isc":"1001000"}},"sn":"0120xxxxmacxxx"}
{{"cmd":"status","usc":"00000000","isc":"1110001"},"sn":"0120xxxxmacxxx"}
{'stat':'dev',{data:['usc':'00000000','isc':'10010001']},'sn':'0120xxxxmacxxx'}
```

need single regex by get only numbers 0-1 format in quotes after **"isc":"***NEED THIS NUMBERS ONLY***"** in single php regex for all formats.
egs

```
$json = '{"env":"stato","usc":"00000000","isc":"00010000","sn":"0120xxxxmacxxx"}';
$find = "isc";    
function find_data($find,$json){
  preg_match('/,[{[]*["\']'.$find.'["\']:["\'](.*)["\'][}]]*,/i', $json, $r);
  return $r;
}
```

json loop solution does not come! json search can only be accepted on one line of code,
I have limited computing and memory resources in atmega 16

thx for help

Comment: Do not use Regex for that. Use json_decode to turn the JSON-String into a PHP array.

Comment: Also, only the first line is actually valid json, the next three lines are all invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = '{"env":"stato","usc":"00000000","isc":"00010000","sn":"0120xxxxmacxxx"}';

$arr = json_decode($json);
$isc = $arr->isc;

print_r($isc);   // Prints:   00010000
```

Comment: thx for resolve - valid json => This is why I was thinking of regexp - I have no control over json syntax

Comment: You could try this pattern, if there is no possibility to receive JSON: _preg_match('/,[{\[]*["\']isc["\']:["\'](.*)["\'][}\]]*,/i', $json, $match1);_

Comment: preg_match('/,[{[]*["\']isc["\']:["\'][0-1]["\'][}]]*,/i', $json, $match1);
would that be correct for only 0/1 as return

Comment: preg_match nice work and very fast 
now just ignoring everything except 1-0 in the same query